# IRequiresSessionState in Windows Phone internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, session, windows-phone, ashx

I have ASP.NET website that checks rights to access some files with ashx handler. So i give the user link to ashx and the handler checks if session was created and there are some values in it - it returns some response with file stream. To make session work in handler i use `IRequiresSessionState` marker interface. And all this works in all browsers(even on iPhone), but doesnt work on internet explorer in windows phone! In IE on WP `context.Session` is not null, but `context.Session.Count` is 0 even tho there are objects, stored in the Session(I use Session objects in other part of the website and it works as usual. Can't get Session objects in .ashx files only)! Tried stock IE in WP8 and UC Browser(which i believe is based on IE9 from WP7) none works :(

Whats is the problem with MS browser again and how to handle it?

Comment: What do you mean with "doesnt work"? the session is not preserved?

Comment: @mdn, oops, sorry, edited..

Comment: are there - (dash), _ (underscore) or other special char in the url of the ashx, or in general of the web app?

Comment: @mdn, nope, there are not. URL looks like this: http://somedomain.com/handlers/musicdownloader.ashx?song=11

Comment: neither in the hostname? (just to be sure =) )

Comment: @mdn :) be sure-no. As i've said the code in ashx file works fine in all the browsers, but IE on WP(works in IE on desktop)

Comment: yes, my question are about a security feature of some IE versions that don't retain cookies for pages with hostname containing special chars. If the session is not maintained easily means that the cookies of the browser aren't mantained.